# React rerenders with "wrong" data

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I have a React App which includes a list that fetches data from an API an renders it. With a button-click this list can be updated (fetching some more data). I want the list to be cleared before the "new" data comes in.
Because my problem is in a pretty big app, I try to explain it abstractly:
Here is my current (abstract) code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const MyList = () => {

    const agesToFetch = [18, 19, 20, 21]
    const [listItems, setListItems] = useState({ "test1": false, "test2": true })

    const updateList = () => {
        // clearing list
        setListItems({})

        agesToFetch.forEach(age => {
            // AJAX request (sending age and some form input and recieving a name with a boolean)
            // for different inputs different results (simulated with random number)
            const result1 = {}
            result1["test" + Math.random().toString().substr(15)] = false
            setListItems({...listItems, result1}) // but here it takes the old already removed state value :(

            const result2 = {}
            result2["secondstest" + Math.random().toString().substr(15)] = false
            setListItems({...listItems, result2}) // here too
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={updateList}>Update</button>
            < table >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name </th>
                        < th > reachable </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                < tbody >
                    {
                        Object.keys(listItems).map(name => {
                            const reachable = listItems[name]
                            return (
                                <tr style={{ "opacity": reachable ? "1" : "0.5" }
                                }>
                                    <td>{name} </td>
                                    < td > {reachable ? "reachable" : "NOT reachable"} </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default MyList
```

The state has some values in the beginning and gets cleared, but the function uses the state value (which isn't cleared yet). So the "old" values, in this example test1 and test2.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting state properly, you should do it with prev:

```
    setListItems(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            result1
        }));
```